# Connect Tab item to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I have created a custom tab bar on my app delegate but cannot seem to connect them to any particular view controllers. This is where I created the item

```
YALTabBarItem *item1 = [[YALTabBarItem alloc] initWithItemImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nearby_icon"]
                                                  leftItemImage:nil
                                                 rightItemImage:nil];
```

But then the app crashes of course because it does not know where to push to. How do I add a view controller to this tab item?

Comment: Have you added a tabBarController too?

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar items are just the UI representations of the buttons on a tab bar. They don't have an associated view controller, their index on a tab bar do. Normally you use a UITabBarController to handle which view controller to show based on the index of the different tab bar items. You could manage it yourself just using a UITabBar but I'd recommend just using the tab bar controller. You should definitely look at the documentation regarding these classes in order to get a better understanding of how they work.